# How to read different type of out parameters from oracle stored procedure?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I have an oracle stored procedure with two numeric output parameters and one ref cursor. below is the structure of the procedure

```
procedure SearchData
(
    p_search in number
    ,p_pages out number
    ,p_pageNumber out number
    ,p_resultSet out sys_refcursor
)
```

I need to read them using c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should install oracle client for c# eg: I always use

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;
```

You need to download it from oracle website to use it in c#

then you can call procedure like below

```
   OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand(); //con is the oracle connection
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SearchData";

  OracleParameter p_search = new OracleParameter();
  p_search.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64;
  p_search.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
  p_search.Value = .....;

  OracleParameter p_pages = new OracleParameter();
  p_pages.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64;
  p_pages.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
  p_pages.Size = 1000;

 OracleParameter p_pageNumber = new OracleParameter();
 p_pageNumber.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64;
 p_pageNumber.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
 p_pageNumber.Size = 1000;

 OracleParameter p_resultSet = new OracleParameter();
 p_resultSet.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
 p_resultSet.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

cmd.Parameters.Add(p_search);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_pages);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_page_number);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_resultSet);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

After execution u can call the out parameter to get the value..like

```
string pages = p_pages.Value.ToString()
```

In case of reference cursor we need to use oracle reader

```
OracleDataReader rd = ((OracleRefCursor)cmd.Parameters[3].Value).GetDataReader(); 
//3 is for 4rth parameter bcos parameter index start from 0
```

then read rd to get the values..

Answer (score 1):

This is how I addressed my requirement

```
   //sample result entity 
   public class SearchResult
    {
        public int NumberOfPagesAvailable { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPageNumber { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ResultItem> ResultItems { get; set; }

    }


        /// <summary>
        /// Method to Create an output parameter
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="paramName">The Parameter name</param>
        /// <param name="paramType">Type of the parameter</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value to set</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static OracleParameter CreateOutputParameter(string paramName, OracleDbType paramType, object value)
        {
            var outParam = new OracleParameter(paramName, paramType, ParameterDirection.Output)
            {
                Value = value ?? DBNull.Value
            };

            return outParam;
        }


        //1     create command

        //2     created the params as below     
            OracleParameter pages = OracleHelper.CreateOutputParameter("p_pages", OracleDbType.Int64, null);
            OracleParameter pageNumber = OracleHelper.CreateOutputParameter("p_pageNumber", OracleDbType.Int64, null);
            OracleParameter resultSet = OracleHelper.CreateOutputParameter("p_resultSet");
        //3     execute using oralce command

        //4     read the param values as below after executing the command
           if (pages.Value != null)
            {
                result.NumberOfPagesAvailable = Convert.ToInt32(pages.Value.ToString());
            }

            if (pageNumber.Value != null)
            {
                result.CurrentPageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(pageNumber.Value.ToString());
            }

                      if (resultSet.Value != null && result.NumberOfPagesAvailable>0 && result.CurrentPageNumber>0)
            {
                OracleRefCursor refCursor;
                    using (refCursor = (OracleRefCursor)resultSet.Value)
                    {
                        using (OracleDataReader rdr = refCursor.GetDataReader())
                        {
                           //iterate through the loop and read the values from the reader
//set ResultItems 
                        }
                    }
            }
```